# Boolean && problem with PGFPlots \addlegendentry

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bugs

While answering this question: [Having problems with drawing a modulus graph in LaTeX (overleaf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619285/having-problems-with-drawing-a-modulus-graph-in-latex-overleaf/619296#619296)

I encountered a strange problem/bug. `&&` in a filter does not work with `\addlegendentry`

```
\documentclass[border= 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
    y filter/.expression={x>2&&x<4)?0:x},
    ] {x};
%\addlegendentry{test} %Does not work with &&
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Linear graph with dip]

The `\addlegendentry` in combination with the `&&` from the filter gives this error:

> Argument of \pgfkeys@sp@b has an extra }. 
> \par  l.12 \end{axis}

Changing `&&` to `||` works fine. Is this a known bug or something I do not understand?

Comment: Seems to be a more or less known bug [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/strange-interaction-between-addlegendentry-and-y-filter-in-pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/strange-interaction-between-addlegendentry-and-y-filter-in-pgfplot). You will probably have to use `not(not(x>2)||not(x<4))` instead of `x>2&&x<4`.